# mock - creating new files (Java)

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito, easymock

how to check **if** without creating a new directory?

```
String st = "exemple";
String path = "exemple";

if (!new File(path).exists() && !new File(path).mkdirs()) {
    throw new ComumException("trocaarquivos.erro.exemple", path);
}
```

**my attempts:**

```
@PrepareForTest(File.class )

 File myFile = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
 PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myFile);
 PowerMockito.when(!new File(anyString()).exists() && !new File(anyString()).mkdirs()).thenReturn(true);
```

and

```
Mockito.when(myFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(myFile.mkdirs()).thenReturn(true);
```

3 days trying to cover this code.

Comment: I suggest that you translate your names and terms into English as it will be easier to get help. @guimas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside ur code extract below into a local variable

```
File f= new File(path);
```

also in the test code

```
@PrepareForTest(File.class ) //Here instead of File it should be the class where new file is created, i.e. YourClass.class
```

i.e.

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassYoureCreatingTheFileInstanceIn.class)
```

now below code should work

```
File myFile = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
 PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myFile);
Mockito.when(myFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(myFile.mkdirs()).thenReturn(true);
```